# How to disable screen flashing on error while using iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2

Using Mac OS Mojave, iTerm2 build 3.2.9, I noticed that when I backspaced on an empty command line, the whole screen flashes white briefly. How can this be disabled?

I checked `Preferences > Advanced > Terminal: Visual bell flashes the whole screen, not just a bell icon.` and it is set to **No**.

I also checked `System Preferences > Accessibility > Audio > Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs` and it is unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

In iTerm2, go to `Preferences > Profiles > (select profile) > Terminal > Notifications` and check **Silence Bell**.

Comment: This didn't work for me with iTerm2 3.4.16 on 10/15/2022